# Remove class on mouseleave

Tags: javascript

I have jQuery code that adds class `feather` to the div on mouseover if it has class `active-s-c-card`. I need to remove this class on `mouseleave`. Would be happy for any suggestions how to improve the current code. Thanks!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("body").on("mouseover" ,function(){
    if ($(".panel-s-c-3").hasClass("active-s-c-card")) {
      $(".panel-s-c-3").addClass("feather");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: If it has to be done exclusively with Javascript why is this all JQuery code?  Are you trying to replace this entire code snippet with **only** vanilla Javascript?

Comment: Hi, You add it when your mouse is over the body right? so the entire page right ? and I don't understand your question you want to delete the class 'feather" when mouse leaves your body ?

Comment: Nathan Champion sorry I made a mistake in the question, I meant jqeury. I edited the question.

Comment: AlexB - I add this class when it hovers "panel-s-c-3". I want to delete feather, when mouse leaves this item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go, when leaving the active-s-c-card element:

```
$(".active-s-c-card").on("mouseleave" ,function(){
  $(this).removeClass("feather")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using vanilla JavaScript:

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('inner');

for (const element of elements) {
  element.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => element.classList.add('red'));
  
  if (element.classList.contains('required-class')) {
    element.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => element.classList.remove('red'));
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
}

.inner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.red {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="inner required-class">
    With class
  </div>

  <div class="inner">
    Without class
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply can apply *removeClass* just you did the *addClass* I am just sharing you the basics not the exact thing so that you understand well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("h1, h2, p").removeClass("blue");
  });
});
</script>
<style>
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="blue">Heading 1</h1>
<h2 class="blue">Heading 2</h2>

<p class="blue">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Remove class from elements</button>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").mouseenter(function(){
    $("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
  });
  $("p").mouseleave(function(){
    $("p").css("background-color", "lightgray");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Move the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The below is jQuery javascript that performs the same function.

```
$(".active-s-c-card").on("mouseover" ,function(){
      $(this).removeClass("feather")
});
$(".active-s-c-card").on("mouseleave" ,function(){
  $(this).removeClass("feather")
});
```

OR

```
document.body.onmouseover = function() {mouseOver()};
document.body.onmouseout = function() {mouseOut()};
function mouseOver() {
  var element = document.getElementByClassName("panel-s-c-3");
  element.classList.add("feather");
}

function mouseOut() {
  var element = document.getElementByClassName("panel-s-c-3");
  element.classList.remove("feather");
}
```